# How to disable GIMP 2.8 splash screen?

Tags: gimp

Since I don't really like any splash screen and I didn't find such info for GIMP, how can I disable the **GIMP version 2.8** splash screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sudo sed -i 's/^Exec=[^ ]*/& --no-splash/' /usr/share/applications/gimp.desktop
```

The sed script inserts the `--no-splash` flag right after the executable's name, this way disabling the splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo sed 's/^Exec=[^ ]*/& -s/' /usr/share/applications/gimp.desktop
```

Comment: Just a small tip to enhance: `sudo sed -i 's/Exec=[^ ]*/& -s/' /usr/share/applications/gimp.desktop`

Comment: Thanks :) And it touched TryExec also, I've fixed this too :)

Comment: You're welcome! Finally, using `s/^Exec=[^ ]*/& -s/` is better than `s/^Exec=[^ ]* /&-s /` because it will work more generally, for example even if the Exec line doesn't have a space at all (command with no args)

Comment: Can you publish the answer? I'll accept it and it'll avoid other members thinking it's still unanswered :)

Comment: I did, but it's really your own answer ;-)

Comment: Why there isn't any `--no-splash` options. You should explain it or I have no other way except to flag it as not an answer

Comment: Please read it more carefully: `-s` is an alias for `--no-splash`